# Grub not showing after windows 10 installation

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I know this question has been asked on the group numerous times but other answers don't seem to help me. I have a Dell Inspiron 32 bit laptop which had ubuntu 14.04 dual booted alongside with windows 8.1. I have tried following solution.

```
    bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
    The operation completed successfully.
```

It didn't help. I tried this as well.

```
    bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx86.efi
```

Still, nothing changed. I couldn't try any bootable-USB based solution due to inaccessibility. Is there any direct solution?

Comment: If you have any android device, I suggest using USB Mountr (https://github.com/Streetwalrus/android_usb_msd/blob/master/README.md) as a workaround. This tool lets you boot any ISO using data cable. Then you just boot live image and update GRUB settings.

Answer (score 1):

Boot from your usb dvd iso to live ubuntu OS then check your boot partition by running:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

Let's say its for example `/dev/sda1`

Run this command:

```
sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
```

Be sure to replace `sda` with the your main disk.

After recheck, run these commands:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

Now you should boot both your OSes

Answer (score 1):

What I think has happened is that the GRUB bootloader got overwritten at some point.

This seems to be the easiest way to fix it:

1. Boot Ubuntu live via a CD or another method
2. Open a terminal in the live session and run

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
   ```

   this installs the boot repair utility, which will reinstall GRUB, and hopefully fix your problem
3. Type `boot-repair` into the console
4. Using the recommended repair will attempt to fix the problem, and if it fails it will generate a pastebin link which you can post on the original question to provide further insight on the problem

Further reading: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair